# A problem relying on van der Waerden's theorem, and the existence of sums divisible by a given number $n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, ramsey-theory

Say we are given a sequence of integers $\{a_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, as well as a pair of integers $n, m$. How can we show that there always exist positive integers $s, r$ such that the sums

$a_s + a_{s+1} + \cdots + a_{s+r -1},
\\
a_{s+r} + a_{s + r + 1} + \cdots + a_{s + 2r - 1},
\\
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \vdots
\\
a_{s + (m-1)r} + a_{s + (m-1)r + 1} + \cdots + a_{s + mr -1}$

are all divisible by $n$.

My first instinct is to use van der Waerden's theorem, perhaps more than once, in order to make the argument work, but I'm having trouble making this argument rigorous. Does this approach even work?

Comment: Could you share your attempt?

Comment: I haven't actually gotten very far, which is why I'm seeking help. Basically the idea would be to inject our sequence onto the natural numbers, and then apply van der Waerden's theorem to get a collection of arithmetic progressions of length $r$ satisfying the desired property. We can then inject this new sequence onto $\mathbb{N}$ and repeat the argument to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is actually correct. Just consider the sums $S_k=a_1+a_2+....+a_k$ and color all integers in $n$ colours depending on their remainder modulo $n.$ More precisely, colour of $k$ is determined by $S_k\bmod n.$ Van der Warden then tells you that there is an arithmetic progression $S_s,S_{s+r},S_{s+2r}...S_{s+(m+1)r}$ with the same remainders modulo $n.$ Substract the latter to get the desired result.